# How to attach invoice PDF instead of packing slip in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-attachments

I want to attach invoice pdf instead of packing slip while creating shipment.
I am using Fooman Email attachment extension version 2.0.8

My magento is 2.2.5 Can anyone know how can I change the attched PDF in shipping confirmation mail ?

Currently it is attaching packing slip but I want to attach invoice pdf in shipping confirmation mail.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem using fooman. We also wanted to send our invoice on shipment creation, while disableing the standard transactional invoice mail on invoice creation. I wrote a module that sends the invoice email together with the shipping email, which is not exactly what you are looking for but maybe you can leverage that.

The module is pretty simple. Except from boilerplate registration.php and module.xml, all you need is to override `InvoiceOrder` from `Magento\Sales\Model` and comment out this line:

`$this->notifierInterface->notify($order, $invoice, $comment);`

like so:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\Sales\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\InvoiceCommentCreationInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\InvoiceCreationArgumentsInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceOrderInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Config as OrderConfig;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice\NotifierInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceDocumentFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceRepository;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\OrderStateResolverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\PaymentAdapterInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Validation\InvoiceOrderInterface as InvoiceOrderValidator;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class InvoiceOrder
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class InvoiceOrder implements InvoiceOrderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $resourceConnection;

    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    /**
     * @var InvoiceDocumentFactory
     */
    private $invoiceDocumentFactory;

    /**
     * @var PaymentAdapterInterface
     */
    private $paymentAdapter;

    /**
     * @var OrderStateResolverInterface
     */
    private $orderStateResolver;

    /**
     * @var OrderConfig
     */
    private $config;

    /**
     * @var InvoiceRepository
     */
    private $invoiceRepository;

    /**
     * @var InvoiceOrderValidator
     */
    private $invoiceOrderValidator;

    /**
     * @var NotifierInterface
     */
    private $notifierInterface;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * InvoiceOrder constructor.
     * @param ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
     * @param OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     * @param InvoiceDocumentFactory $invoiceDocumentFactory
     * @param PaymentAdapterInterface $paymentAdapter
     * @param OrderStateResolverInterface $orderStateResolver
     * @param OrderConfig $config
     * @param InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepository
     * @param InvoiceOrderValidator $invoiceOrderValidator
     * @param NotifierInterface $notifierInterface
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        InvoiceDocumentFactory $invoiceDocumentFactory,
        PaymentAdapterInterface $paymentAdapter,
        OrderStateResolverInterface $orderStateResolver,
        OrderConfig $config,
        InvoiceRepository $invoiceRepository,
        InvoiceOrderValidator $invoiceOrderValidator,
        NotifierInterface $notifierInterface,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->invoiceDocumentFactory = $invoiceDocumentFactory;
        $this->paymentAdapter = $paymentAdapter;
        $this->orderStateResolver = $orderStateResolver;
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->invoiceRepository = $invoiceRepository;
        $this->invoiceOrderValidator = $invoiceOrderValidator;
        $this->notifierInterface = $notifierInterface;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $orderId
     * @param bool $capture
     * @param array $items
     * @param bool $notify
     * @param bool $appendComment
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\InvoiceCommentCreationInterface|null $comment
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\InvoiceCreationArgumentsInterface|null $arguments
     * @return int
     * @throws \Magento\Sales\Api\Exception\DocumentValidationExceptionInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Sales\Api\Exception\CouldNotInvoiceExceptionInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     * @throws \DomainException
     */
    public function execute(
        $orderId,
        $capture = false,
        array $items = [],
        $notify = false,
        $appendComment = false,
        InvoiceCommentCreationInterface $comment = null,
        InvoiceCreationArgumentsInterface $arguments = null
    ) {
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection('sales');
        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        $invoice = $this->invoiceDocumentFactory->create(
            $order,
            $items,
            $comment,
            ($appendComment && $notify),
            $arguments
        );
        $errorMessages = $this->invoiceOrderValidator->validate(
            $order,
            $invoice,
            $capture,
            $items,
            $notify,
            $appendComment,
            $comment,
            $arguments
        );
        if ($errorMessages->hasMessages()) {
            throw new \Magento\Sales\Exception\DocumentValidationException(
                __("Invoice Document Validation Error(s):\n" . implode("\n", $errorMessages->getMessages()))
            );
        }
        $connection->beginTransaction();
        try {
            $order = $this->paymentAdapter->pay($order, $invoice, $capture);
            $order->setState(
                $this->orderStateResolver->getStateForOrder($order, [OrderStateResolverInterface::IN_PROGRESS])
            );
            $order->setStatus($this->config->getStateDefaultStatus($order->getState()));
            $invoice->setState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice::STATE_PAID);
            $this->invoiceRepository->save($invoice);
            $this->orderRepository->save($order);
            $connection->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            $connection->rollBack();
            throw new \Magento\Sales\Exception\CouldNotInvoiceException(
                __('Could not save an invoice, see error log for details')
            );
        }
        if ($notify) {
            if (!$appendComment) {
                $comment = null;
            }
            //$this->notifierInterface->notify($order, $invoice, $comment);
        }
        return $invoice->getEntityId();
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is setup `events.xml` and observe `sales_order_shipment_save_after`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name='sales_order_shipment_save_after'>
        <observer name='SendInvoiceWithShipment' instance='Vendor\Module\Observer\SendInvoiceWithShipment'
        />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer leverages standard Magento 2 transactional email `$this->_invoiceSender->send($invoice);` like so:

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender;

class SendInvoiceWithShipment implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_invoiceSender;

    public function __construct(
        InvoiceSender $invoiceSender
    ) {
        $this->_invoiceSender = $invoiceSender;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getShipment()->getOrder();
        if (!$order) {
            // Dont send invoice if order is not provided 
            return; 
        }

        $invoices = $order->getInvoiceCollection();

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {

                try {
                    $this->_invoiceSender->send($invoice);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // Do something if failed to send                          
                }

        }               

        
    }
}
```